# Find master project root directory in sbt multi-project

Tags: sbt, multi-project

Is it possible to reference the master project from a subproject, in a multi-project sbt file?
I am writing a custom task, and I need to find two directories:

- from the master project: the baseDirectory
- from the subproject: the target

Of course, each of these are available inside their own projects. But I need to access them in the same code.
How can I do that?

The project layout is:

```
some/dir/build.sbt
    val masterRoot = baseDirectory.value.getAbsolutePath // this works
    lazy val root = (project in file(".")).aggregate(subproject)
some/dir/subproject/build.sbt
    lazy val someTask = TaskKey[String]("someTask")
    someTask := {
        val subprojectTarget = target.value.getAbsolutePath // this works
        val masterRootBroken = baseDirectory.in(root).value.getAbsolutePath // root is not found
        // I need access to subprojectTarget AND masterRoot here
    }
```

Alternatively, can I set a value into a SettingKey in the graph in the master project, and read it in the subproject?

Answer (score 1):

I think there are two options available to you

First option is multi files project structure that you already have

`build.sbt`:

```
val sub = (project in file("sub"))
val root = (project in file("."))
```

*Note:* None of the above lines are mandatory. They are defined just to represent some possible additional logic like `aggregate`.

And `sub/build.sbt` with content

```
val root = (project in file("..")) //Note that ".." is used to refer to root project folder
val combinedPath = TaskKey[String]("combinedPath")
combinedPath := {
  target.value.getAbsolutePath + baseDirectory.in(root).value.getAbsolutePath
}
```

Second one is to combine all `build.sbt` files into one `build.sbt` in root project with content

```
val combinedPath = TaskKey[String]("combinedPath")
val sub = (project in file("sub"))
  .settings(
    combinedPath := {
      target.value.getAbsolutePath + baseDirectory.in(root).value.getAbsolutePath
    }
  )
lazy val root = (project in file("."))
```

Definition of task `combinedPath` is done in `settings` of `sub` project and it can refer to `baseDirectory.in(root)` of `root`.